# Updating state in a class based component and re-rendering it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

first i am defining a state in class and rendering it using props, after that I am trying to update the state on clicking a button and on adding an event handler to the button  but

when I am trying to console log the updated state after the nameChangeHandler and I am not able to see the updated state but I can see the previous state though

this is my App.js file

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Person from './Person/Person';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [
      { name: 'sagar', age: 22 },
      { name: 'nitin', age: 18 },
      { name: 'ankita', age: 21 },
    ],
    otherData: 'some other value',
  };
  changeNameHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      persons: [
        { name: 'sagar', age: 22 },
        { name: 'nitin', age: 18 },
        { name: 'ankita-nanda', age: 91 },
      ],
    });
    console.log(this.state);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <h1>Hello world!!!!</h1>
        <Person
          name={this.state.persons[0].name}
          age={this.state.persons[0].age}
        />
        <Person
          name={this.state.persons[1].name}
          age={this.state.persons[1].age}
        >
          i'm going to college
        </Person>
        <Person
          name={this.state.persons[2].name}
          age={this.state.persons[2].age}
        />
        <button onClick={this.changeNameHandler}>Switch Names</button>
      </div>
    );
    // return React.createElement(
    //   'div',
    //   { className: 'App' },
    //   React.createElement('h1', null, 'hope this works!!')
    // );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and this is my Person.js file

```js
import React from 'react';

const person = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        Hey, my name is {props.name} and I'm {props.age} yeras old!
      </p>
      <p>
        {props.children}--{props.name}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default person;
```

[this is the screenshot of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3VXy.png)

Answer (score 0):

setState is async so if you try to console log after your click event the same state will be there.

If you want to check the updated state you can try to console.log it above render.

```
render() {
console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <h1>Hello world!!!!</h1>
        <Person
          name={this.state.persons[0].name}
          age={this.state.persons[0].age}
        />
        <Person
          name={this.state.persons[1].name}
          age={this.state.persons[1].age}
        >
          i'm going to college
        </Person>
        <Person
          name={this.state.persons[2].name}
          age={this.state.persons[2].age}
        />
        <button onClick={this.changeNameHandler}>Switch Names</button>
      </div>
    );
    // return React.createElement(
    //   'div',
    //   { className: 'App' },
    //   React.createElement('h1', null, 'hope this works!!')
    // );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
changeNameHandler = () => {
  this.setState({
    persons: [
      { name: 'sagar', age: 22 },
      { name: 'nitin', age: 18 },
      { name: 'ankita-nanda', age: 91 }
    ]
  });
  setTimeout(() => {
   console.log(this.state);
  }, 0);
};
```

`setState()` is async function, so, it take some fraction of time to run and next line of code is executed.

As state is not updated yet, you will get the previous state.

`setTimeOut()` does the trick and runs after state updated.